# Phonegap Index.html reset each launch

Tags: android, cordova

Why my www/index.html keeps reseting(default phonegap) after I run this command `phonegap run android`? And this `cordova emulate android` do the same but why it's different from the first command, plus give me this error: 

edit: I'm using IntelliJ IDE.

> BUILD SUCCESSFUL
>   Total time: 14 seconds
>   WARNING : no emulator specified, defaulting to api18
>   Waiting for emulator...
>   shell.js: internal error
>   Error: spawn EMFILE
>       at errnoException (child_process.js:980:11)
>       at ChildProcess.spawn (child_process.js:927:11)
>       at exports.spawn (child_process.js:715:9)
>       at Object.exports.execFile (child_process.js:607:15)
>       at Object.exports.exec (child_process.js:578:18)
>       at execSync (/Users/fernando/hello/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/shelljs/shell.js:1793:9)
>       at Object._exec (/Users/fernando/hello/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/shelljs/shell.js:1130:12)
>       at Object.exec (/Users/fernando/hello/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/shelljs/shell.js:1487:23)
>       at Object.module.exports.sleep (/Users/fernando/hello/platforms/android/cordova/lib/emulator.js:255:15)
>       at Object.module.exports.wait_for_emulator (/Users/fernando/hello/platforms/android/cordova/lib/emulator.js:221:14)
>   ]

Comment: When you do `cordova build` it copies the all the files from the `www` folder into your platforms location for the `www` folder, replacing whatever was there previously. Might that be why it's being replaced?

Comment: That could be! I'm sure that I forgot do the build!

Comment: Sorry, whenever i do the `cordova build` it resets too...

Comment: Are you modifying the `www/index.html` file? 'cause that should only happen if you're modifying the file in the separate platform folders…

Comment: Yes, I modified at `www/index.html` file. But at `platform/android/asset/www/index.html` is the same as I modified

Answer (score 1):

you need to change the code in the [app_path]\www, not inside the platforms directory